# How can i Remove NFC HAL modules from the Android 13 , PIxel 6 pro (Raven) source code

Tags: android, android-source, hal, android-13

i want to remove nfc hal module from the device.

i want to remove NFC HAL module from the google pixel 6 pro (Raven) which is running with Android 13 aosp version.

To Remove that i tried in `device-raven.mk` in the path `AOSP_ROOT/device/google/raviole/` inside that file i identified the `android.hardware.nfc@1.2-service.st` and i removed that line.

and also i removed the `manifest_nfc.xml` . after that i buld the source code and flash it on device.

then if see `lshal` still it is showing the following lines, and also the **NFC** Functionality still working.

```
android.hardware.nfc@1.0::INfc/default 
android.hardware.nfc@1.1::INfc/default 
android.hardware.nfc@1.2::INfc/default
```

can any one tell me how to remove nfc hal module from the device.